# Laravel 5 Redirect After Logout - How to Redirect Back?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I want to redirect back to where the user has been, after he logs out successfully, because I have methods that are accessible even if logged out.

I guard every method in my **PhotosController** except **@show**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => 'show']);
}
```

To set the redirect after logout I set the property in my **AuthController** like this:

```
protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/customLogoutPage';
```

But I want to redirect the user back to where he has been, since he can see the View even without being locked in.

I tried something in this direction:

```
protected $redirectAfterLogout = redirect()->back();
```

But my browser says: "Unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'

How is it possible to use a redirect back to the view where the user has been, before he logged out.

Comment: You can't get the built-in AuthController to do this. You'll have to make your own version of its logic.

Comment: Build your controller which can do this....

Comment: :/ ok thanks. Do you happen to have an introduction to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in logout-method only accepts a string, you are passing a function to it. If you want this behaviour you have to implement your own logout-method in your `AuthController`.

Fortunately, this is very simple:

```
public function getLogout()
{
    Auth::logout();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

That's it.

For reference, this is the original function used by Laravels `AuthenticatesUser` trait:

```
/**
 * Log the user out of the application.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function getLogout()
{
    Auth::logout();

    return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getLogout()
{
    Auth::logout();

    return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/customLogoutPage');
}
```